# How to fix Xcode 4's useless uncommenting behavior

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 4, selecting the Uncomment command only works properly if the comment slashes are at the beginning of the line.

So using ⌘/ on this line:

```
// sudo make me a sandwich
```

results in this:

```
sudo make me a sandwich
```

But when the comment is indented:

```
    //sudo make me a sandwich
```

⌘/ results in this:

```
//    //sudo make me a sandwich
```

If my cursor is in a line that is a comment, I want ⌘/ to uncomment it. Period. Does anyone have a workaround/fix for this?

Comment: There's also another gotcha - you cannot select a block and uncomment it if there is any break in the "beginning of line slashes".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> a few times to un-indent it, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> to uncomment, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> to re-indent it. A little lame, but you asked for a workaround, and there it is.
2. File a bug at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com), so that it can be brought to the attention of the engineers and fixed in a future release.

Comment: Good call—submitted a radar report.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an actual solution but the bug report/workaround has it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 6 (at least), this now works.

It does have the caveat, however, of not automatically aligning uncommented code.

In this example

```
    func doSomething() {
        doSomethingElse()
//        someOtherThing()
        //alertUser()
        // logTask()
    }
```

Hitting `cmd-/` will on each of the commented lines results in:

```
    func doSomething() {
        doSomethingElse()
        someOtherThing()
        alertUser()
         logTask()
    }
```

So in effect, Xcode is only removing the `//`, not adjusting the whitespace to properly align the lines. If you comment out lines without adding additional whitespace, all will work perfectly. I however, add the extra space after comments to make that line more readable, and so this still contains a bug (or feature request) for me...